# Swift ios reset viewcontroller hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

In storyboard my app is designed as:

Navigation VC -> VC1

What I am trying to do is to segue to another VC but reset the menu-hierarchy so that i **dont** have the old VC's stacked in the backgound

What I want to do is:

Navigation VC -> VC1 -> VC2 -> *NEW VC with Navigation reseted*

So when a user logs in and enters the account VC/Page the navigation stack should be resetted when hitting the account VC/Page

Is this possible to do?

Comment: basically You don't want to add it to the stack ? is that what you want ?

Comment: You can show the view controllers you don't want to have in the stack modally perhaps. But otherwise it's a bad idea to have a back button that does not lead "back" anymore.

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Yes. I want to display a menu button instead of a "back" button on the new VC

Comment: @Animal Okey I can try. I dont want a back button I want to replace it with a menu button on the new VC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to add the view controllers to your navigation controller, every View controller you navigate to you can set that as the root view  controller of your navigation controller and it won't be added in your stack.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let yourViewController: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("respectiveIdentifier") as! ViewController
let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.setViewControllers([yourViewController], animated: true)
```

Comment: In the view controller from where you are navigating to the next view controller, if you are doing that on click of a button within that action.

Comment: It says the VC have no member named "window"
class LoginViewController: UIViewController

Comment: check the edit, if you are using it in a ViewController you need to access self.view.window and in app delegate you need to access it as self.window

Comment: Can i know the reason for accepting and then unaccepting and down voting my answer

Comment: Does it work if the current VC is displayed as modal?

Comment: you need to push all the view controllers but they won't be added in the stack

Comment: I got it to work. But how do I remove the two VC's before? Both the menu VC and login VC is still active. They both are showed up as modals

Comment: Could you add the flow , and what is the reason to present them modally?

Answer (score 0):

My solution same as above but one line less

```
let yourViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerId") as? YourViewController

        let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.setViewControllers([yourViewControllerObejct!], animated: true)
```