# what navigation alternatives are there to UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting into iOS development, and am struggling a bit with screen flow. All the documentation I read states that UINavigationController is for representing a UI backing hierarchical data. What if I don't have hierarchical data?

Example - I have a multi-step form, where I don't need to go back. The first step asks me what type of user I am, and from there, there are two distinct sets of questions asked, on a separate view (or series of views). What I've done right now is build 3 separate view controllers, linked them with segues in interface builder and manually invoke the segues when needed. This feels wrong to me, but making this fit into a navigation controller doesn't feel right either - there's nothing hierarchical about what I'm doing.

What's the preferred approach here?

Comment: i think the manually segueing approach is fine if you never intend to go back

Comment: If you want to use a UINavigationController and and want to work it as per your requirement , kindly check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301209/swift-ios-reset-viewcontroller-hierarchy/33302066#33302066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right that you don't need `UINavigationController` there. You can either present your VC or then `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:self];` one of which you must be doing. If on QuestionsVc there are multiple screens then you can use `UINavigationController` there.